# How to check if all records of an instance have one of many values from a list of values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I'm looking for a solution for a complex query.

Goal : I want to know if all record of an instance have a value, and do some action when all records of the instance have the same value.

**Order Model :**

```
has_many :items
Columns : treated
```

**Item Model :**

```
belongs_to :order
Columns : order_id / state
```

**Seed exemple :**

```
Order.create
@item1 = Item.create(order_id: 1, state: pending)
@item2 = Item.create(order_id: 1, state: pending)
```

In a callback action, on the Item Model, I've done :

```
def treatment
    self.order.items.each do |item|
      if item.state = "order_accepted" or item.state = "order_refused"
        item.order.update_attributes(treated: "true")
      end
    end
  end
```

So i'm trying to have a result like :

**"If all my Items have the states "order_accepted" or "order_refused", then update the Order to 'treated'."**

Please help!
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question title does not match the description. You're not checking whether "all records have **the same value**", you're checking that all records have **one of many values** (from a list).

There are a few issues with your attempt:

```
self.order.items.each do |item|
  if item.state = "order_accepted" or item.state = "order_refused"
    # ...
```

1. Redundant use of `self`
2. Use of `=` is **setting** the value, rather than *checking for equality*. (This would be done with `==`.)
3. By looping through all `items` like that, you're updating the `order` multiple times.
4. ...And since you're performing the check for *each* `item`, rather than *all* items, you're not checking that they *all* have the desired value.

A minimal change to your attempt that would *work* is:

```
if order.items.all? { |item| item.state == "order_accepted" || item.state == "order_refused" }
  order.update_attributes(treated: "true")
end
```

However, that's not a great solution since you're loading all objects into memory and looping through them. This is inefficient, especially if there are lots of `items`. A better approach is to perform the check *directly in `SQL`* rather than in `ruby`:

```
if order.items.where.not(state: ["order_accepted", "order_refused"]).empty?
  order.update_attribute(:treated, "true")
end
```

To tidy this code up a little, I would define that query as a **scope** on the `Item` model, such as:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  scope :not_completed, -> { where.not(state: ["order_accepted", "order_refused"]) }
end
```

And then perhaps define a method on the `Order` model too:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  def complete?
    items.not_completed.empty?
  end
end
```

Then in the code above, you can just write:

```
def treatment
  # ...
  order.update_attribute(:treated, "true") if order.complete?
  # ...
end
```

Also, I suspect that should really be `true` rather than `"true"`. `true` is a boolean; `"true"` is a string. Use the correct data type for the job.

Rails may be automatically casting the value to a boolean on your behalf (?), but I would consider it bad practice to use the wrong data type, regardless.

Comment: the `order` appears to be what is being updated so might make more sense for `Order` to have a `complete?` method such that `items.not_completed.empty?` then the call back would just be `order.update_attribute(:treated, true) if order.complete?`. Also I believe rails handles the type casting for `true` and `"true"` without issue.

Comment: Yeah, true. I'll add that suggestion as an extension, thanks.

Comment: Hi @TomLord & engineersmnky, thanks a lot(!) for the solution. It's pretty elegant. The redondant use of Self was the most tricky problem form me (with the simple "="). Thanks again guys!